# Number of rows inserted into SQLite db is negative

Tags: python, sqlite, insert, rowcount

I'm trying to insert new records into `SQLite` database from `Python` code.

```
  con = sqlite.connect(connectionString)
  cur = con.cursor()
  countOfNewItems = 0
  for ...
    try:
      con.execute("insert or ignore into items ...")
      countOfNewItems += cur.rowcount
    except:
      cur.close()
      con.close()
      print "Error when inserting item '%s' to database." % item
      exit(1)
  cur.close()
  con.commit()
  con.close()
  print "%d new items have been inserted." % countOfNewItems
```

My code reports negative number of inserted records (-5141).

Because my database was empty, I could find out how many records were inserted via command line

`select count(*) from items;`

4866

Could you advise me what's wrong. Why the two values don't match and why it's negative?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try `cur.execute` instead of `con.execute`.  `cur.rowcount` then returns 1 for me for a simple insert.

Answer (score 4):

http://docs.python.org/library/sqlite3.html#sqlite3.Cursor.rowcount

> Although the Cursor class of the sqlite3 module implements this attribute, the database engine’s own support for the determination of “rows affected”/”rows selected” is quirky.

and

> As required by the Python DB API Spec, the rowcount attribute “is -1 in case no executeXX() has been performed on the cursor or the rowcount of the last operation is not determinable by the interface”.

Comment: Too fast...almost exactly what I was in the middle of typing.  I recommend printing out the rowcount through each loop to see how "quirky" it is.

Comment: This was my stupid mistype. I noticed it when I tried to print rowcount as Mark said. I typed `con.execute` and to my unluckiness it worked as if I typed `cur.execute`. But I think I can accept this answer, it may be good for others to know possibility of this mistake.